# Arabic Language Encoding Problem in PHP and ODBC(Sybase)

Tags: php, encoding, odbc, sybase, arabic

I am a PHP Developer and Recently I develop a web site using PHP and I connect to a Syabse Database using ODBC.

My database connection is ok and I can display the data in my web pages but I face a problem when arabic data is displayed as it is viewed as squares and not understanding symbols.

I can not change the Database language encoding and it is correct as some other arabic data is displayed well.

I tried the same configuration used in that web page but it does not work too.

I read many realted problems and I tried some solutions and I read about UTF-8, ISO, Windows and Unicode langauge Encodings and I tried to change the HTML Meta tag to display the arabic words but the problem is not solved.

I think my PHP file language Encoding itself may have a problem.
Can I change the PHP file language Encoding ? How to do that if it is possible ?

Is there any solution to dispaly Arabic coming from Database well in PHP web pages ? It is a boring problem :(

I will appreciate any hint or suggestion to solve that problem but please mention your reference and put and example if it is available.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changing the Meta tag isn't enough.

Assuming you want to change your environment to UTF-8, you need to make sure that the following is UTF-8 encoded:

- The database tables
- The database connection.
- The page's encoding (in the Meta tag, or preferably the `content-type` header)

the PHP file's encoding is irrelevant, unless it contains non-ASCII content itself. In that case, you need to adjust its encoding as well, usually in your IDE's "Save as" dialog.

Comment: And the page's encoding in the http header: if you put a meta http-equiv, you must have the same http header set ^^

Comment: @G.Qyy yeah, I just thought of that myself :) Added.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responce but I do not use MySQl. I use ODBC to connect to Syabse Database. I think SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'; may not work with it. I tried to change the PHP file using Save As but i do not find encoding in options.

Comment: @user yeah, I just realized and removed the links, sorry. I don't know how to change the encoding in Sybase

Comment: @user maybe this helps: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sag1/html/sag1/sag1444.htm

Comment: thanks alot for your support but I can not change the database. I can only do whatever I want in the web server and PHP web site. I mean I can change the way to display the data stored in database without changing the original data itself. It is a constraint for our business rules.

Comment: @user I see. There may be some ODBC settings you can change to get the data in the right character set, but I do not know them.

Comment: yes I already tried to put the Encoding in ODBC connection but it makes my database connection fail .. I put it as UTF-8 to support both Arabic and English.

Comment: @user well, as a last resort, if you know what encoding you are getting from the database, you could convert all the data using `iconv()`: http://php.net/iconv

Comment: @G.Qyy true, but if you set a `Content-type` header, you don't need the meta tag

Comment: @Pekka You are right, but if you set the http-equiv Content-Type meta tag, you must set the header Content-type, and the http-equiv Content-Type meta is mandatory...

Comment: excuse me, in fact, it's seems not to be mandatory, but highly recommended. (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_9)

Comment: I tried all what mentioned but the problem still exists !! Actually I get depressed as no logical cause for that and I edited the file many times and I replaced it with another working one but it gives the same results. It seems Arabic Language has some problem with PHP although I like PHP very much and I read alot about it.

Comment: @user have you tried playing around with `iconv()`? I'm pretty sure this is solvable that way, even if you can't change the database. You'd just need to find out what encoding the database uses, and specify that as the source encoding. http://php.net/iconv

Comment: @Pekka thanks for your answer and comments. the problem is fixed when i replaced the file with another one and I changed the content of it to what I want although the two files has the same configuration but sometimes strange problems happened .. Thank you and I would like to have new and useful answers from you for any new questions :)